# Keeping a php script active

Tags: javascript, php, gd

I was thinking of uploading some huge images onto my webpage and figured I could possibly optimize the load using a special image viewer with zoom functionality. As I've understood from long ago is that browsers have certain limits when it comes to image dimensions, and possibly memory as well. The workaround for the simple task of just displaying the image on a page would be to resize it server-side in `PHP` and display that.

However, with the idea of allowing zoom capabilities so one can look at all the little details (essentially seeing the picture as 1:1 scale), the problem I'm having is being able to provide that "zoom" quickly. As I understand it, a `PHP` script is run once when called, then cleared from memory when done. I made a test with a 40MB picture and `imagecreatefrompng();` took 5 seconds, meaning each time a client zoomed (and panned), they'd have to wait 5 seconds before the image is updated.

The question becomes if it is possible to keep a `PHP` script running and have its memory preserved for the duration it's needed? Like when a client clicks on a thumbnail, a call goes out to the `PHP` to load the image and it returns the resized image, but remains active and retains the `$img` in memory, waiting for more instructions. When the client zooms, a new call goes out to the `PHP` with the dimensions needed, and instead of having to reload the image it resizes and crops the original `$img` it still has in memory. When the client is done by closing the viewer, tab or browser, a call goes out to the `PHP` saying it's done which triggers it to `imagedestroy(original);`, clear memory, and stop.

(maybe have some kind of timeout for cases when the client unexpectedly shuts down and no "stop" signal is sent)

Comment: Insteas of doing what you said, simply use a zoom function JS on the image. (this is usually known as magnifying glass)

Comment: The general mechanism for keeping PHP _data_ across request lifecycles, would be a session. But `imagecreatefrompng` returns a _resource_, not just data - so that resource would have to be restored from the stored session data each time.

Comment: Sounds like you want to separate this into a couple of components - one component will take the source images, processing them into smaller unit 'tiles' which will be cached on the server for quick retrieval later. This process will run asynchronous and be transparent to the user. Then you should have your JS and PHP loading images from this set of cached tiles.

Comment: Your question is interesting! Effectively PHP runs for the request but perhaps it could be possible to use [shared memory and semaphores](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) to keep the resource open somehow. Effectively, I understand you don't want to download the 40MB file just for a portion of it. You could also prepare some tiles like it's done for maps and then just retrieve the tile you need for the zoom.

Comment: "waiting for more instructions" is not like PHP works. You need to send the whole source image again on a succeeding request

Comment: @KenLee Yeah, the idea of keeping it all client-side had crossed my mind, but like I said, the client may not have the memory to keep those (quick maths)  almost 500MB of raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having really big images I would consider creating tiles once the image is uploaded and then use a JS library to handle the display and zoom functionnality like most map libraries. [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) is typically one of these.

For the tiles generation, you could use [Deepzoom](https://github.com/jeremytubbs/deepzoom) or [Zoomify](https://packagist.org/packages/daniel-km/zoomify) as they are made to work with *OpenSeadragon*.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to pre-tile anything, however OSd does seem to be very optimized... Wondering if I should redo all images into `DZI`s. :muchthonkiness: I'll look into this. Thanks.